# Error HH100: Network ropsten doesn't exist

Tags: solidity

I get this error everytime I try to launch the contract with npx hardhat --network ropsten run scripts/deployPizzaHeadNFT.js

```js
    require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
    const dotenv = require("dotenv");
    dotenv.config();
    // This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
    // https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
    task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
      const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
    
      for (const account of accounts) {
        console.log(account.address);
      }
    });
    
    // You need to export an object to set up your config
    // Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more
    
    /**
     * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
     */
    module.exports = {
      solidity: "0.8.4",
      networks: {
        rinkeby: {
          url: process.env.REACT_APP_RINKEBY_RPC_URL
          accounts: [process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY],
        },
      },
      etherscan: {
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ETHERSCAN_KEY,
      },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have ropsten in your config. Only rinkeby

change it to:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_RINKEBY_RPC_URL
      accounts: [process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ETHERSCAN_KEY,
  },
};
```

and change your url to ropsten RPC url.

Comment: Also if you just copied someones code and are trying to create your own NFT project I strongly recommend you don't, before you know at least the basics. You don't want to deploy vulnerable contracts to mainnet. There is enough hacks already.

Comment: Error HH100: Network ropsten doesn't exist

Comment: did what you said and this is the message I got

Comment: Do you use ropsten RPC_URL?